# How to unit-test the presence of form fields in a Symfony2 form with eventlisteners

Tags: php, forms, unit-testing, symfony, symfony-2.4

This is on Symfony2.4:

I am trying to test (in a unit test) the presence of some fields in a form which are supposed to be added dynamically by an event listener. Based on the data passed to the form, certain fields should be present and others not in one case and a different combination in another case.

The form itself is correct, it does work (seemingly) as intended.

My form class' `MyFormType::buildForm()` method roughly being:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', null, array(
        'label' => 'name'
    ));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)

        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if ($data->getSomeField() === 123) {
            $form->add('field1');
        } else {
            $form->add('field2');
        }            
    });     
}
```

And in the unit test I get a form and set some data (passing the data to the `create()` method does not make any difference):

```
$this->form = $this->getService('form.factory')->create(new MyFormType(), null, array('csrf_protection' => false));
$this->form->setData($data);
```

And right after this I try to dump `$this->form->all()` to see if the dynamically added fields are present, but they are not.

`$this->assertTrue($this->form->has('field1'));` also fails.

Any ideas what have I missed, or should have done differently in order to have a fully initialized form (with all the relevant event listeners executed and all fields present, dynamically added or not)?

Comment: This isn't what unit testing is for as unit testing is for testing a class in isolation and this has multiple interacting modules, some on the front end and some on the back end.  This is more an integration testing or functional testing project, probably involving Selenium. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29

Comment: Yes, you are right. Strictly speaking it is not unit testing. But I would like to have this still. I already have it for a number of other forms, my problem being with the ones which rely on event listeners to manipulate form fields.